# LibGDX BitmapFont not falling down with the body simultaneously

Tags: android, kotlin, libgdx, game-physics, box2d

Trying to draw a box with text inside its center, but the text doesn't fall down simultaneously with the body. The text moves a little slower than the polygon, and sometimes the text even not exactly on the right position when body stops moving.

I tried to place a circle inside the polygon, it can moves simultaneously with the polygon.

Please give some advice on doing this, and any other idea to do this without using BitmapFont? Thanks.

```
fun draw(batch: SpriteBatch, alpha: Float) {
    batch.begin()
    if (!projectionMatrixSet) {
        shapeRenderer.projectionMatrix = batch.projectionMatrix
    }
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled)
    shapeRenderer.color = dColor
    shapeRenderer.rect(boxBody.position.x - dw, boxBody.position.y - dh, dw*2, dh*2)
    shapeRenderer.end()
    batch.end()

    batch.begin()
    if (!projectionMatrixSet) {
        circleRenderer.projectionMatrix = batch.projectionMatrix
    }
    circleRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled)
    circleRenderer.color = Color.WHITE
    circleRenderer.circle(boxBody.position.x , boxBody.position.y, 0.4f)
    circleRenderer.end()
    batch.end()

    batch.begin()
    font.data.setScale(0.05f,0.05f);
    val layout = GlyphLayout(font, "3", Color.BLACK, dw*2 , Align.center, true);
    font.draw(batch, layout, boxBody.position.x - dw, boxBody.position.y + dh)
    batch.end()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `font.setUseIntegerPositions(false)` so it isn't rounding off the font position to the nearest whole number worldspace coordinates when it gets drawn. You should also use bilinear or trilinear filtering on your font so it won't look wonky as it moves. So use `MipMapLinearLinear` for the minifying filter and `Linear` for the maximizing filter.

Other problems I notice in your code:

- Don't surround your `shapeRenderer` and `circleRenderer` usage with SpriteBatch `begin()`/`end()` calls. They have nothing to do with SpriteBatch. You don't need to begin a SpriteBatch to retrieve its projection matrix. Every call of `batch.end()` is a potential performance hit.
- Don't create a GlyphLayout in your draw loop. You're creating a new one on every frame of animation. That will generate a lot of garbage for the GC, which can cause hiccups in your frame rate. Only create a new one when the text changes. And you might consider using a Pool for them if this happens during gameplay.

Comment: `font.setUseIntegerPositions(false)` is working good. Also, does it need to change all position and size variable (x, y, width, height) to Integer? `begin()`/`end()` are removed from `ShapeRenderer` , and `GlyphLayout` is placed in `init()`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using `Linear` on both minifying and maximizing display in normal, but if I set minifying to `MipMapLinearLinear`, it only shows a rectangle.

Comment: If you change the filter to use mip maps after the texture is already loaded, it won’t work. You should enable mip maps in the font, atlas, or skin file you’re using so the texture is loaded with mip maps. The font will look clearer with mip mapping turned on, especially when drawn smaller than its original size, which will happen on screens with lower resolutions.

Comment: You don’t need to change anything to integers. Changing that setting to false means the font is not internally rounding off the numbers it uses to draw itself. The reason a font does this seemingly unwanted behavior by default is because when libgdx was first designed, phones had very weak GPUs where you wanted to avoid linear filtering of any kind if you could help it so the way to get fonts to look clear was to draw them pixel perfect to a camera where one pixel is the same size as a world unit. And to prevent blurriness in this situation, you need to draw exactly aligned to screen pixels.